# Slow query - Union All

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, optimization

I have this query below, but it's taking 3 hours to run... do you have any idea how could I optimize this query for better performance?

```
SELECT *
FROM stg.F_STG_ORCAMENTO F_STG_ORCAMENTO
WHERE 1=1
AND F_STG_ORCAMENTO.COD_CONTA LIKE '6%'
AND F_STG_ORCAMENTO.COD_CONTA NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT F_STGT_CNT_EXPLOR_CTB_GERAL.C_CNT_GERAL
                                      FROM STG.F_STGT_CNT_EXPLOR_CTB_GERAL F_STGT_CNT_EXPLOR_CTB_GERAL
                                      WHERE F_STGT_CNT_EXPLOR_CTB_GERAL.C_LOLOJA=F_STG_ORCAMENTO.C_CENT_CUSTO
                                      AND INPUT(substr(put(F_STGT_CNT_EXPLOR_CTB_GERAL.DTA_CNT_EXPLOR,8.),1,4),4.)=F_STG_ORCAMENTO.DTA_ANO
                                      AND INPUT(substr(put(F_STGT_CNT_EXPLOR_CTB_GERAL.DTA_CNT_EXPLOR,8.),5,2),2.)=F_STG_ORCAMENTO.DTA_MES
                                      AND F_STGT_CNT_EXPLOR_CTB_GERAL.C_CNT_GERAL=F_STG_ORCAMENTO.COD_CONTA)
AND F_STG_ORCAMENTO.V_NUM_CUSTOS > 0

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM stg.F_STG_ORCAMENTO F_STG_ORCAMENTO
WHERE 1=1
AND F_STG_ORCAMENTO.COD_CONTA LIKE '94%'
AND F_STG_ORCAMENTO.COD_CONTA NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(F_STGT_CNT_EXPLOR_CTB_GERAL.C_CNT_ANL,4,9)
                                      FROM STG.F_STGT_CNT_EXPLOR_CTB_GERAL F_STGT_CNT_EXPLOR_CTB_GERAL
                                      WHERE F_STG_ORCAMENTO.C_CENT_CUSTO=F_STGT_CNT_EXPLOR_CTB_GERAL.C_LOLOJA
                                      AND F_STG_ORCAMENTO.DTA_ANO=INPUT(substr(put(F_STGT_CNT_EXPLOR_CTB_GERAL.DTA_CNT_EXPLOR,8.),1,4),4.)
                                      AND F_STG_ORCAMENTO.DTA_MES=INPUT(substr(put(F_STGT_CNT_EXPLOR_CTB_GERAL.DTA_CNT_EXPLOR,8.),5,2),2.)
                                      AND SUBSTR(F_STGT_CNT_EXPLOR_CTB_GERAL.C_CNT_ANL,4,9)=F_STG_ORCAMENTO.COD_CONTA)
AND F_STG_ORCAMENTO.V_NUM_CUSTOS > 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/503834 Basically, no one can give you a real answer because it is highly dependent on your dataset and environment. Even experts will be guessing.  However, if you use the Oracle tools to inquire into the nature of these tables, indices, and qeries you will actually collect information that you can present here so you get useful answers. Hint: you want to look at how to profile and fetch plans from your DB.

Comment: `NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ...` is useless. Remove the `DISTINCT` - result will be the same.

Comment: What are functions `INPUT` and `PUT`? Maybe poor performance is coming from there.

Comment: Check the explain plan of query.

Comment: Using short aliases for the tables could at least help to make your query more readable ..